# Count the corresponding matching value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want the count of every corresponding matching row. I get the corresponding value using the left join now the count part is missing. Here is my query of left join

```
SELECT bloglikes.post, blogdata.id
FROM bloglikes
LEFT JOIN blogdata
ON bloglikes.post=blogdata.id
```

Above is the image of output:

[image]

Now I want output like: Id 2 have 4 entries or row.

Comment: Seems like a basic task. Use `COUNT()`

Answer (score 2):

Use count:

```
SELECT count(*), blogdata.id
FROM bloglikes
LEFT JOIN blogdata
ON bloglikes.post=blogdata.id
GROUP BY blogdata.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much it work's .... @EO102030